# How can I update only Xcode from a shell script?

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, command-line

`man softwareupdate` says `--list` will "List all available updates." but it does not list Xcode. Manually opening the App Store shows an Xcode update.

How can I update only Xcode from within a script <strike>*without updating the entire system and macOS itself* (by running `softwareupdate --install --all`)</strike>?

Perhaps [mas-cli](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas) can do it, but the preferred method to install chokes on the problem I would be using it to solve:

```
$ brew install mas
Error: Your Xcode (7.2) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 8.3 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```